# OpenCV FPS Optimisation

Tags: linux, opencv, intel, frame-rate

How can I increase `opencv` video FPS in Linux on Intel atom?  The video seems lagging when processing with opencv libraries.

Furthermore, i m trying to execute a program/file with `opencv`
system(/home/file/image.jpg);

however, it shows **Access Denied**.

Comment: profile your application, find the bottleneck, then it will be clearer what to do, otherwise people will be guessing.

Comment: Are you compiling in release mode? Opencv is very slow when compiled with debugging information.

Comment: im not very sure which mode im using, i compile withh g++.. what's the  difference between these two modes and how to compile with each mode?

Comment: You need to be much more specific with your question. Is it lagging when simply grabbing frames from the video and displaying them, or when you also do some processing on them?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do to improve performance.  Using OpenGL, GPUs, and even just disabling certain functions within OpenCV.  When you capture video you can also change the FPS default which is sometimes set low.  If you are getting access denied on that file I would check the permissions, but without setting the full error it is hard to figure out.

First is an example of disabling conversion and the second is setting the desired FPS.  I think these defines are changed in OpenCV 3 though.

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB , false);

cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS , 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems you have a problem that your frame buffer is collecting a lot of frames which you are not able to clear out before reaching to the real-time frame. i.e. a frame capture now, is processed several seconds later. Am I correct in understanding?

In this case, I'd suggest couple of things,

1. Use a separate thread to grab the frames from VideoCapture and then push these frames into a queue of a limited size. Of course this will lead to missing frames, but if you are interested in real time processing then this cost is often justified.
2. If you are using OOP, then I may suggest using a separate thread for each object, as this significantly speeds up the processing. You can see several fold increase depending on the application and functions used.